# Is there a sed equivalent to awk -F ':' '{print $2}'?

Tags: linux, sed

Maybe someone can help me to find (the most simply) the equivalent of this following awk command with sed:

```
echo "first:second:third"|awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
second
```

Comment: Should be migrated to stackoverflow.

Comment: Any particular reason to use sed?

Comment: No, there is no pragmatic reason, it's more than to improve my knowledge ;)

Comment: A quest for knowledge is always a good thing, but `awk` (or `cut`) are both better tools for this than `sed`: No reason to spin up a regex engine when you  just need to split input based on a delimiter.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using a regex in my perl example below, but just splitting on the delimiter is simpler.

Comment: `echo second` passes all the tests.

Comment: @RoundTower Did I have you as a student in the Unix orientation class? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo "a:b:c" | sed 's/^[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*$/\1/'
b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut`.

`echo "first:second:third" | cut -f 2 -d ":"`

I think `sed` is the wrong tool for this. `awk` is probably the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

This works too

```
echo "a:b:c" | sed 's|.*:\(.*\):.*$|\1|'
```

Is saves the text between (...) as \1 and then substitutes it for the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Perl alternative:

```
echo "first:second:third" | perl -F':' -lane 'print $F[1]'
```